# Make a directory with name stored in a string

Tags: java, directory, properties-file

I am reading values in from a properties file as below:

```
public class Backup {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    try{
        //load properties file for reading
        prop.load(new FileInputStream("src/com/db_backup/db-backup_config.properties"));

        String password = prop.getProperty("db.password");
        String port = prop.getProperty("db.port");
        String name = prop.getProperty("db.name");
        String userid = prop.getProperty("db.userid");
        String tables = prop.getProperty("db.tables");
        String host = prop.getProperty("db.host");

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

}

I want to make a directory with the name stored in the string userid. How could I do this? Also is this the best way to read in a properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directory using Java like this -

```
File file = new File("C:\\dir");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        if (file.mkdir()) {
            // success
        } else {
            // failure
        }
    }
```

And regarding reading properties, it's usual to do it the way you've done.

Comment: I managed to figure out the directory, but was still unsure about the properties. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to make a directory you would create a file object using the userid String like:

```
File f = new File(userid);
```

Now you want to make a directory out of that if it does not exist.

```
if(!f.exists()) {
    f.mkdir();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you could use [`File#mkdir()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) like so,

```
File f = new File(userid);
if (f.exists()) {
  if (f.isDirectory()) {
    System.out.println(f.getPath() + " already exists");
  } else {
    System.out.println(f.getPath() + " (non-directory) already exists");
  }
} else {
  if (f.mkdir()) {
    System.out.println(f.getPath() + " created");
  } else {
    System.out.println(f.getPath() + " not created");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I continued my fiddling and was able to do it with:

```
File theDir = new File(host);
        if(!theDir.exists()) {
            System.out.println("Creating Directory: " + host);
            boolean result = false;

            try{
                theDir.mkdir();
                result = true;
            } catch (SecurityException se){
                //handle
            }
            if(result){
                System.out.println("DIR created");
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thanks to those who replied.